# Translate something that is in a fashion way

Tags: traducción

### English

I have a line of text thats describes something that can be done in a fashion way, How would you translate it to Spanish?

> This allow the user to extend scalar data type system in an
>   object-oriented fashion.

I was translating that as:

> Esto permite al usuario extender los tipos de datos escalares del sistema en un estilo orientado a objetos.

### Spanish

Tengo una línea de texto que describe cómo puedes hacer algo de una cierta manera. ¿Cómo  se debe traducir? En este caso es como seguir un "paradigma orientado a objetos", puse que sería como "un estilo", pero no estoy seguro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Traducir `fashion` como `estilo` me parece correcto, sin embargo el texto:

> This allow the user to extend scalar data type system in an object-oriented fashion

Yo lo traduciría como:

> Esto le permite al usuario extender un sistema de tipos de datos escalares en un estilo orientado a objetos

ya que, como yo lo veo, *scalar data type* es un atributo de *system*